on firefox and firefox developer i cant see the elements of a class on the console
when i use console.log(class) or use a string template the elements i put for each object of the class it says undefined
mokepones.forEach((mokepon) => {
  MokeponChoice = `
    <input type="radio" name="mascota" id=${mokepon.nombre} />
    <label class="tarjetas-mokepon" for=${mokepon.nombre}>
      <p>${mokepon.nombre}</p>
      <img src=${mokepon.foto} alt="${mokepon.nombre}">
    </label>
  `
  contenedorTarjetas.innerHTML += MokeponChoice
  console.log(mokepon.nombre)
})

is there a plugin or something that can let me see these elements in firefox developer?
i tried downloading firefox developer to see if i could see it
edit: here is the class
class Mokepon {
    constructor(nombre, foto, vida) {
        this.nombre
        this.foto
        this.vida
        this.ataques = []
    }
}

let hipodoge = new Mokepon('Hipodoge', './assetsMP/mokepons_mokepon_hipodoge_attack.webp', 5)
let capipepo = new Mokepon('Capipepo', './assetsMP/mokepons_mokepon_capipepo_attack.webp', 4)
let ratigueya = new Mokepon('Ratigueya', './assetsMP/mokepons_mokepon_ratigueya_attack.webp', 3)

hipodoge.ataques.push(
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-agua' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-agua' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-agua' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-tierra' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-fuego' },
)

capipepo.ataques.push(
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-tierra' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-tierra' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-tierra' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-agua' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-fuego' },
)

ratigueya.ataques.push(
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-fuego' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-fuego' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-fuego' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-agua' },
    { nombre: '', id: 'boton-tierra' },
)

mokepones.push(hipodoge, capipepo, ratigueya)

here's how it looks on the page

What do you mean by "class" here? The code you posted is not at all clear; what exactly is it that you want to see (or do or whatever)?

If you're getting undefined, the elements of the mokepons array don't have those properties. Try doing console.log(mokepon) to see what the actual values are.

You need to pass the constructor parameters to the class properties.
Firefox isn't the issue here.
class Mokepon {
    constructor(nombre, foto, vida) {
        this.nombre = nombre
        this.foto = foto
        this.vida = vida
        this.ataques = []
   }
}

